# OpenTok Session Connection Issue (Javascript/Rails Application)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, session, dom-events, opentok

This is a basic video chat I wanted to create with 2 users connected.
After having done a bit research on opentok Tutorials, I was able to create the 2 way chat without Server SDK.

But When I created the rails server side app, I was unable to get the 2 way chat, rather the link was only creating single session and was not accepting any other users.

I have included the gem opentok in Gemfile.

**Problem:**
Only Single Video Div appearing, even after a existing screen present in another tab. i.e., I open the link, I get a video screen, When I open the same link in another tab, I get a single video screen instead of two. (Some issue with session connections).

Code from Controller:

```
class AuthController < ApplicationController

require "opentok"


def index
  config_opentok

  session = @opentok.create_session
  @id = session.session_id
  @token = session.generate_token

end

private

  def config_opentok
    if @opentok.nil?

      @opentok = OpenTok::OpenTok.new API_KEY, 'SECRET'

    end
  end

end
```

I have entered correct Api_key and Secret above as given from Opentok dashboard.

Code from View:

```
<div id='myPublisherDiv'></div> 
<div id='subscribersDiv'></div> 

<script src='//static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js'></script> 
<script> 


  var apiKey = API_KEY; // used correct Api_key in APP
  var sessionId = '<%= @id %>'; 
  var token = '<%= @token %>';
  var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId); 
  session.on({ 
      streamCreated: function(event) { 
        session.subscribe(event.stream, 'subscribersDiv', {insertMode: 'append'}); 
      } 
  }); 
  session.connect(token, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    } else {
      session.publish('myPublisherDiv', {width: 320, height: 240}); 
    }
  });
</script>
```

I have tried some other variants, adding event handlers etc, but nothing worked for me. **Any Help appreciated. Provide sample codes if possible.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are creating a new session for each page load. That means each visitor is getting a different session ID so the two will never be able to subscribe to each other.

Instead, you need a way to store a generated session ID (such as a database). Then you think about how you want to place visitors in the same session, such as using the URL for unique "rooms". When you have a page load that should serve a session ID that was previously generated, read the value from the database.